# Is there a Material 'Chips' UI component in the IOS HIG?

Tags: gui-design, ios, material-design, human-interface-guideline

If so, is there a resource somewhere I can grab it or some documentation on it? Basically just want to have a list of tags that a user can delete. If the HIG has something i'd prefer to use that.

Comment: It doesn't appear that there is. Are you allowed to use Google Material guidelines? Generally when Apple is silent on something, we look there.

Comment: @StacyH Google uses material design for their iOS apps, so theoretically Apple won't reject an app because of it (even though they might not recommend it).

Answer (score 4):

Starting in iOS 13, [UISearchToken](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchtoken) is available for use in [UISearchTextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchtextfield).

UISearchToken appears similar to input chips (more information in the [WWDC19 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/?time=1485)) and there are also libraries like [token-ui](https://github.com/hootsuite/token-ui) which support back to iOS 11.